# "Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation"

Tags: multi-signature, signature, raw-transaction

I want to broadcast signed transaction but I get this error how can I solve this I get this everytime.

"Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation"

RAW hex

020000000145226bdae23c0248dd1beb34cf3ea779573ed90085887a1dd118292a2d94c978010000006a473044022071689eac31b547c3986a3cea835c6086dffc343ea328c52763949b804505c1aa02201b4aa94a61a943be4200543b93ec88caa25c970c65a4c8da2d6b982031dba3c8012103e5845754ad4902ab0a92fcd5a0c5dc48c8d1fc92425ba0adcfde81a78655f56efdffffff02f41a0000000000001976a9146f6de5a183c82bd2a409bac1f216eed7e50f044888ac04310700000000001976a914239c1161dcf7bae9170367a3809ae3d3b9f793fb88ac0d1c2500

Comment: There are some [existing questions concerning the same error message](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=Signature+must+be+zero+for+failed+CHECK%28MULTI%29SIG+operation) - does any of them help?

Answer (score 2):

This message indicates the signature verification failed for signature `3044022071689eac31b547c3986a3cea835c6086dffc343ea328c52763949b804505c1aa02201b4aa94a61a943be4200543b93ec88caa25c970c65a4c8da2d6b982031dba3c8` against public key `03e5845754ad4902ab0a92fcd5a0c5dc48c8d1fc92425ba0adcfde81a78655f56e`.

There is most probably an issue with how you create the signature.

Comment: how can I solve this issue what I must add/remove/change ?

Comment: By generating a valid signature for the public key.